# Reason behind using DNA primer in PCR techcnique while RNA primer use in replication in vivo?

Tags: human-genetics

I have went through Lehinger ( biochemistry book) and cooper ( cell Biology) but i didn't find my answer.
plese help me

Comment: Your question isn't very clear; could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The (very) basic answer to your **question about in-vitro vs. in-vivo primer usage** is:

1. **In-vivo** - Although either (DNA or RNA primers) can be used for in-vivo primer extension biochemistry, DNA primers are not available (not made) in living cells. Therefore all natural in-vivo primer chemistries utilize RNA primers.
2. **In-vitro** - DNA primers are easily synthesized, inexpensive, functional, and substantially more stable (less likely to be degraded). DNA primers are therefore primarily used for most in-vitro purposes (i.e. PCR and other in-vitro primer extension applications).

Beyond that, all other reasons (complex evolutionary reasons vs. human choices in-vitro); involving subtle differences between RNA and DNA chemistry, structure, and function, similarly can play a role. The links below may be helpful to address some of these differences.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Nucleic_Acid/Difference_between_DNA_and_RNA

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(molecular_biology)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, initiation of DNA replication *in vivo* at a defined origin of replication, requires an enzyme with DNA primase activity.  DNA primase is a DNA-dependent RNA polymerase that generates short RNA primers that are used to prime DNA synthesis by the DNA polymerase holoenzyme at a so-called replication fork.

The classical polymerase chain reaction (PCR), on the other hand, is a way for humans to use an *in vitro* method to amplify relatively large amounts of double-stranded DNA from a specific fragment, using a DNA template target and two artificial, single-stranded DNA oligonucleotide primers (along with dNTP substrates, buffer, Mg++, a thermostable DNA polymerase, and a programmable thermocycler).

So the goals, or outcomes, of the two processes that you are trying to compare seem vastly different to me.  Replicating a chromosome is presumably to keep an organism alive, and reproducing, and dividing, to produce progeny.  Amplifying a desired DNA fragment is a tool to allow some subsequent process or assay to occur.

Your question does not have a clear sense (to me).  There is no stated requirement for biochemical reactions created by human scientists to in any way be limited, or constrained by reactions that occur inside a living cell.